# TS2339 Error after check with instanceof function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

**according to Typescript Narrowing, you can use getDate() method without any error if use instanceof and check Date type, for example
**

```
function logValue(x: Date | string) {
  if (x instanceof Date) {
    console.log(x.getDate());
  } else {
    console.log(x + 'is a string');
  }
}
```

** but, I create a function for instanceof and i have an error, now
**

```
export function isInstanceofDate(data: any): boolean {
  return data instanceof Date
}

function logValue(x: Date | string) {
  if (isInstanceofDate(Date)) {
    console.log(x.getDate());           // error 
  } else {
    console.log(x + 'is a string');
  }
}
```

show error TS2339: Property 'getDate' does not exist on type 'string | Date'.

change config in tsconfig but i can not solve problem

Comment: • In what sense does this have to do with Node.js or JavaScript? It seems like a pure TypeScript question • You've got a typo, you can't mean to check `isInstanceOfDate(Date)`. Please [edit] to fix it. • TS doesn't automatically propagate control flow outside functions; if you want that effect you can turn `isInstanceOfDate` into a custom type guard function as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbrbEm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?